# How to set Anonymous access to Site Collection using Powershell

Tags: powershell, site-collection

I like to give Anonymous access to Site collection using power shell. How I will do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement like the following:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint.contoso.com/sites/sitecollection
$web.AnonymousState = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb+WebAnonymousState]::Enabled
$web.Update()
```